# show entire output of expected and received in failed test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a test that is comparing two sets, and when it fails the output is of the form:

```
    - Expected
    + Received

      Set {
        Position {
          "x": 0,
    -     "y": 0,
    +     "y": 2,
        },
        Position {
    -     "x": 1,
    -     "y": 1,
    +     "x": 0,
    +     "y": 0,
        },
        Position {
    -     "x": 2,
    +     "x": 1,
          "y": 1,
        },
        Position {
    -     "x": 2,
    -     "y": 0,
    +     "x": 1,
    +     "y": 2,
        },
      }
```

I find this very hard to read as it's just a text diff and the real discrepancy is obscured (the sets differ by 2 elements but the output makes it hard to tell which)

This is an app I created via `create-react-app`, and I'm running the tests using `npm test` or `yarn test`. I thought that the command line arg `--expand` would do the trick but this doesn't seem to change the output (using `yarn test -- --expand` for instance) I thought the issue was passing command line args thru `npm` and `yarn` but `--silent` seems to be working as expected so I think that's working.

I'm totally new to this modern front-end environment so forgive me if I'm mixing up tools here ...

This is the test, in case it's relevant:

```
test('calculate neighbors on the edge of the board', () => {
    let actual = neighbors(new Position(0,1));
    let expected = new Set([
        new Position(0,0),
        new Position(1,1),
        new Position(2,1),
        new Position(2,0),
    ]);
    console.log(actual);
    console.log(expected);
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
})
```

Those `console.log`s are suppressed by `--silent` which is why I think the args are being passed through. But maybe I misunderstand `--expand` ?

contents of `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "tzaar-js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.10",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "konva": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-konva": "^16.13.0-3",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yarn does not require addituional `--`
Just `yarn test --expand`.
Please share your npm scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure what to share but this is in package.json (I've added to the post)

Comment: using `--` in your command `yarn test -- --expand` isn't required

Comment: @KiranManiya right, yarn does print a warning with that. but if i remove the extra `--` the output is the same, and the same as npm. not sure it matters to the question?

Comment: @Unbywyd i'm not sure i understand, the console logs were just to see if the arguments were passed through yarn/npm. does your comment have something to do with  `--expand` ?

Comment: To see console.log you can try using the [`--verbose`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#verbose-boolean) option

Comment: @butttons sorry for the confusion, the problem is not that the console logs are not visible, the problem is I want the testing framework to print something understandable without me logging it manually. of course I can log the results but that is not going to be sustainable over a full test suite. the logs were just to test passing arguments through to Jest, I should have been clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest seems to have been changed in v24 to give less information. In Jest 23.6.0 the output you got is preceded by:

```
Expected value to equal:
  Set {{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 0}}
Received:
  Set {{"x": 0, "y": 2}, {"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 1, "y": 2}}
```

This is not shown when the Jest version is changed to 24.9.0, which is the default with     react-scripts v3.4.1 used in your `package.json`.

A workaround in your test is to use two `.toContain` matchers instead of a `.toEqual`:

```
expect(actual).toContain(expected);
expect(expected).toContain(actual);
```

This produces (from the first assertion):

```
Expected value: Set {{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 0}}
Received set:   Set {{"x": 0, "y": 2}, {"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 1, "y": 2}}
```

Note that, unlike the `.toEqual` equivalent, `.toContain` fails if the order is different between the two sets, so you will need to convert the sets to arrays and sort them to compare properly.

Comment: Another potential solution could be to create a custom matcher to act like `.toEqual`, but I haven't looked into the feasibility of this fully yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the expect and format the error at your own convenience:

```
test('calculate neighbors on the edge of the board', () => {
    let errorFound = false;
    let actual = neighbors(new Position(0,1));
    let expected = new Set([
        new Position(0,0),
        new Position(1,1),
        new Position(2,1),
        new Position(2,0),
    ]);
    console.log(actual);
    console.log(expected);
    try {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('your personalized error here');
      errorFound = true;
    }

    expect(errorFound).toBe(false); // this is not needed, but helps detecting errors
})
```

*being creative, don't mind me here*

```
test('calculate neighbors on the edge of the board', () => {

let actual = neighbors(new Position(0,1));
let expected = new Set([
    new Position(0,0),
    new Position(1,1),
    new Position(2,1),
    new Position(2,0),
]);
console.log(actual);
console.log(expected);
try {
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Mismatch between expected and actual neighbors');
  for (let i=0;i<expected.length;i++){
     try{
         expect(expected[i]).toMatch(actual[i])
     } catch (inner){
         console.error(`At pos ${i} expecting ${expected[i]} but found ${actual[i]}`);
     }
  }
}
})
```

This needs a zillion checks (e.g.: does it print `undefined` if actual gets short of Positions or it just breaks?) but would be great if worked, wouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: thanks for the help but the whole point is the testing framework do this work for you